# preg_match_all to scrape found word between html tags

Tags: php, preg-match

I have the following piece of code which should match the provided string to $contents. $contents variable has a web page contents stored through file_get_contents() function:

```
if (preg_match('~<p style="margin-top: 40px; " class="head">GENE:<b>(.*?)</b>~iU', $contents, $match)){
                    $found_match = $match[1];
                }
```

The original string on the said webpage looks like this:

```
<p style="margin-top: 40px; " class="head">GENE:<b>TSPAN6</b>
```

I would like to match and store the string 'TSPAN6' found on the web page through (.*?) into $match[1]. However, the matching does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: It would be useful to know which information is static and which is dynamic in the string. Your pattern works on my xampp btw. `$match[1] == 'TSPAN6'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your suggestion did not work.

After some hours of looking through the html code I have realized that the regex simply had a blank space right after the colon. As such, the code snippet now looks like this:

```
$pattern = '#GENE: <b>(.*)</b>#i';
preg_match($pattern1, $contents, $match1);
if (isset($match1[1]))
{
    $found_flag = $match1[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match( '#GENE:<b>([^<]+)</b>si#', $contents, $match );
$found_match = ( isset($match[1]) ? $match[1] : false );
```